# Continuous bijection from $(0,1)$ onto $\mathbb{R}$ has a continuous inverse

Tags: solution-verification, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous bijection from $(0,1)$ onto $\mathbb{R}$. Then show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

We can use the fact that $f$ has to be a monotone function and so is $f^{-1}$. Together with the fact that surjective real valued monotone function is continuous we can conclude. Is there any other approach?

Comment: find a continuous pointed bijection between their one point compactifications, apply the theorem that says it must be a homeomorphism, then restrict its inverse to $\mathbb{R}$? :)

Comment: You can fairly easily make an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument, again using the fact that the function must be monotone.

Comment: Specifically, given $x\in (0,1)$ and $\epsilon>0,$ choose $\epsilon'=\min(\epsilon, x/2, (1-x)/2),$ so that $[x-\epsilon',x+\epsilon']\subset (0,1).$ Then choose $\delta=\min(|f(x-\epsilon')-f(x)|,|f(x+\epsilon')-f(x)|).$

Comment: The one-point compactification argument is nice, because it generalizes, If $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous bijection with $X$ Hausdorff and $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact for any compact subset $K\subseteq Y,$ I think we can conclude $f$ is a homeomorphism. You might need something in addition, not sure.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you should need $Y$ Hausdorff too, right?

Comment: Whoops, yes, I got it backwards. You need $Y$ Hausdorff, not $X.$